# Binding a TextBlock property inside Footer control with another property inside DB window user control, but both in the same MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF form displaying a DB data in a DataGrid. The form is simple – MainWindow with two user controls. The first user control contains the DataGrid, and the second one is a footer control, where I have a TextBlock displaying the items count. I can apply different filters to the DataGrid, so the items count will be changed at run time.

The question is how to attach Items Count from the DBview control to the Text property of TextBlock inside the Footer control?

Below is a short version of how I load the data into the DataGrid and also count the items:

```
private int itemsCount;

public string ItemsCount
{
    get { return itemsCount.ToString(); }
    set { itemsCount = Convert.ToInt32(value); }
}

private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    context = new MDBEntities();

    mapInfoViewSource = ((CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("mapInfoViewSource")));
    IQueryable<MapInfo> mapQuery = GetMapsQuery(context);
    mapInfoViewSource.Source = mapQuery.ToList();

    itemsCount = mapInfoDataGrid.Items.Count;
}
```

Below is the XAML code in the Footer control:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="DisplayedNum" x:FieldModifier="public" Foreground="#FF569CD6" Margin="10,3,3,0" 
               Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:DBviewer}}, Path=ItemsCount}"  />
```

Also, I don’t use MVVM, just a code behind. I have tried several different bindings but the TextBox stays empty. Could you please suggest a solution? Thanks.

Comment: Ancestor relative source only works if the controls are contained in each other, try referencing the control using ElementName.

Comment: Thanks! I’ve tried a lot of different combinations, but neither one works. Both controls are visible from the Main window, but cannot see each other, because they are on a “different branches”. So I have to learn MVVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also, I don’t use MVVM, just a code behind.

That's your main issue. There is a reason why MVVM is *the* recommended design pattern for XAML based UI applications and this is one of them.

If both your `UserControl`s share the same view model, you could easily bind the `TextBlock` to the `Count` property of the source collection that is bound to the `DataGrid` in the other control.

You cannot bind to a property of the other control using a `RelativeSource` nor `ElementName` binding because they reside in different naming scopes.

So you will either have to re-design your application (learn and use MVVM!) or you will have to get a reference to the other control programmatically in the code-behind of the footer Control using a visual tree helper method.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! At least I will not waste my time trying to do some sort of binding. I understood, even both user controls are part of the same main window, they are on a different branch of the tree and they cannot see each other. I read a lot about the benefits of using MVVM, but nobody mentioned about this one. And this one, I think is very important. In a simple form like this with header, footer and main area user controls, they cannot communicate each other without a common view model class. Thanks once again.